# Creating Remote Actors Programmatically is not working

Tags: scala, akka, akka-remote-actor, akka-remoting

I am creating remote akka actor programmatically.

Below is the Program -

```
package remoting.programatic.demo

import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import remoting.config.demo.RemoteActor

object RemoteActorApp extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem("RemoteNodeApp", ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("RemoteProgrammatically"))
  val remoteActor = system.actorOf(Props[RemoteActor], name = "remoteActorAddr")

  remoteActor ! "Hello!"

  val actorSelection = system.actorSelection("akka.tcp://RemoteNodeApp@localhost:2553/user/remoteActorAddr")
  Thread.sleep(4000L)

  actorSelection ! "Hello!"

}
```

The configuration is -

```
RemoteProgrammatically {
  akka {
    actor {
      provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
      deployment {
        /remoteActorAddr {
          remote = "akka.tcp://RemoteNodeApp@localhost:2553"
        }
      }
    }
    remote {
      enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
      netty.tcp {
        hostname = "localhost"
        port = 2553
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output after running the program is -

```
[INFO] [12/27/2017 10:37:30.053] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [12/27/2017 10:37:30.378] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://RemoteNodeApp@localhost:2553]
[INFO] [12/27/2017 10:37:30.379] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://RemoteNodeApp@localhost:2553]
[INFO] [12/27/2017 10:37:30.418] [RemoteNodeApp-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] [akka://RemoteNodeApp/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://RemoteNodeApp/user/remoteActorAddr#-766312407] to Actor[akka://RemoteNodeApp/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [12/27/2017 10:37:34.419] [RemoteNodeApp-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] [akka://RemoteNodeApp/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://RemoteNodeApp/user/remoteActorAddr#-766312407] to Actor[akka://RemoteNodeApp/deadLetters] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

The message I sent to actor is always going into the dead letters. 
Looks like `remoteActorAddr` is not created successfully at RemoteNodeApp actor system.
Any Idea why the actor is not created and why the message always goes into dead letters.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://RemoteNodeApp/user/remoteActorAddr#-766312407] to Actor[akka://RemoteNodeApp/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered.
```

The above excerpt from your logs is saying the dead letters mailbox is encountered when sending a string message *from* the remote actor. The remote actor is apparently sending a message to `sender()`, which is dead letters in this case because the messages that the remote actor received were sent with `tell` (`!`) from outside an actor. In other words, the remote actor *is* created successfully, but the following two messages are sent from a non-actor, which causes `sender()` in the remote actor to resolve to dead letters:

```scala
remoteActor ! "Hello!"
...
actorSelection ! "Hello!"
```

From the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#tell-fire-forget) (emphasis mine):

> ```scala
> actorRef ! message
> ```
>
> If invoked from within an Actor, then the sending actor reference will be implicitly passed along with the message and available to the receiving Actor in its `sender(): ActorRef` member method. The target actor can use this to reply to the original sender, by using `sender() ! replyMsg`.
>
> **If invoked from an instance that is not an Actor the sender will be `deadLetters` actor reference by default.**

Send the messages from another actor, or use the [`ask`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html?language=scala#ask-send-and-receive-future) pattern (which creates an internal actor to handle the reply).